# Check if values of an ArrayList - IN A ROW - is the same

Tags: java, sql, arraylist, system.out

I have a question I have not seem to find answered. 
So I have an ArrayList consist of 2 types of values: Won or Loss. The values comes in different order. I need to check how many times the same value comes from the top of the Array in order to show e.g. a user have won 5 times in a row.

```
ArrayList <String> wins = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.print(wins);

[Won, Won, Won, Loss, Loss, Won, Won, Loss, Loss, Loss, Loss, Loss, Won, Won, Won, Won, Won, Loss]
```

Can anyone figure this out? I have tried for a while now but unfortunatly I have not been able to come to a solution yet. T

Comment: are you trying to find the maximum count of a given value which are in consecutive order?

Comment: have a counter(int), max(int) and loop through array, when ever you see Won increment counter and check is it greater than max if not proceed with next iteration, if you see Loss reset the counter again back to 0.

Comment: Satish im trying to count how many times in a row a "win" happends. Starting from the top of the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Assuming the List has minimum one element

```
List<String> wins = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Won", "Won", "Won", "Loss", "Loss", "Won", "Won", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Won", "Won", "Won", "Won", "Won", "Loss"});
        System.out.println(wins);
        String value = wins.get(0);
        int maxValue=1;
        int count = 1 ;
        for(int i=1;i<wins.size();i++){
            if(wins.get(i) == wins.get(i-1)){
                count++;
                if(count >= maxValue){
                    maxValue = count;
                    value = wins.get(i);
                }
            }else{
                count=1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(value + " : " + maxValue );
```

Comment: Hey man! Thank you so much for the code. This works excellent. However, I needed to modify it a bit, as I'm only trying to count the wins.

Comment: @tobiasmadsen17 please accept the answer if it solves your problem.